# Creating OAuth2 service provider without UI

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

I am writing a set of Puppet modules that deploy WSO2 ESB & Identity Service and the API & authentication services we are providing to a client.

For the most part, I have been able to figure out which XML config files I need to update to automatically configure the WSO2 product.

However, I can't work out how to automatically provision an OAuth2 service provider via the config files.  I can create and successfully use an OAuth2 service provider through the Identity Service mgmt console, however I'd really rather not have to do that as a manual step when my aim is to configure a set of machines using Puppet to automatically provision an OAuth2 provider.

To confirm, screenshot of the UI below that I am trying to apply settings for via an XML config file, rather than having to do it in the UI:

[image: Screenshot...]

After some googling, is the correct directory /repository/conf/identity/service-providers?
If so, could somebody point me in the direction of an example where this is used for configuring an OAuth2 service provider?

If not, any more pointers would be gratefully received!

Many thanks
Chris

Comment: Im not quite sure whether you are able to do that. Because AFAIK those information are put in the db. Not in a config file. You can read more on config db http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2015/04/wso2-identity-server-data-dictionary.html

Answer (score 1):

In case of searching configuration file for adding OAuth configuration without management console UI, you are in the right place. As you specified you can use the configuration in /repository/conf/service-providers/default.xml.

When you add service provider you have to call `IdentityApplicationManagementService`. You can use `IdentityApplicationManagementServiceStub` to call `IdentityApplicationManagementService`. When you add OAuth configuration you have to call `OAuthAdminService`. You can use `OAuthAdminServiceStub` to call `OAuthAdminService`. After creating the service provider and OAuth configurations separately, you have to bind service provider with created OAuth configs.

Note that I will recommend to check the source code in UI classes which used to add service providers, OAuth configs and binding those two. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was really trying to avoid writing any code to interact directly with the WSO2 source code as I'd like to be able to easily deploy a service provider as part of a set of Puppet configuration scripts.

I don't have much experience with WSO2 so I'm assuming that it is the case that methods you mention would need to be called from code that I'd need to write myself?

Comment: you don't need to be familiar with wso2 code base to add service provider configuration? It is just a web service. you need to call the web service with required parameters. This can easily be done with a java app. since you are creating a set of puppet scripts, you need to check how to call a web service using puppet scripts

Comment: Ah, understood, that makes sense.  That led me to this blog article: http://blog.lasindu.com/search/label/OAuthAdminService, which looks like it is exactly what I need!

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Did the blog article help you fix this problem? I am getting errors on the last step of this article. @ChrisWilson